# VLOOKUP True statement returns closest match for some rows and N/A for others?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have created a VLOOKUP to return a body weight value recorded on a date closest to a Power value recorded on different days.

It works for the majority of the rows but for others it return N/A. Looking through the data manually there is a date close that proceeds that should be returned.

Dates are in ascending order.

Index-Match gave the same output.

Can anyone help?
(Excel novice here)

Thanks,
Lewis

Comment: Please add the vlookup formula you are using.

Comment: Can you show some of your data plz?

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information, it's possible the N/A's are caused by dates entered as text.